# How to deal with the shell input before it executed in Bash or zsh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

everyone. I am a bash/zsh user(Linux). I want to realize the following things.

First, input the command in the bash/zsh shell, like:

**$** *wonderful:*

In fact, a program named `wonderful:' doesn't exists. What I want is **to deal with the input-string with a function(or program) before the shell executes the command**. More specifically, when the command input is `wonderful:', the shell deliver the input to my function/program, and that's all the shell does.

Does there exists a way to realize such a thing? Either bash or zsh is ok. Thanks a lot for your attention!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. Does piping `cat` to your program achieve what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function called `command_not_found_handle` which will be invoked any time an entered command is not found. This is supported in bash 4.0 or later; the equivalent `zsh` function is the similarly named `command_not_found_handler`.

A simple example that intercepts a misspelling of `printf`, but leaves any other unknown command as unknown.

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [[ $1 == pirntf ]]; then
        printf "${@:2}"
    else
       printf "Command not found: $1"
       return 127
    fi
}
```

Comment: i also thought about suggesting that, but he wants to handle the command 'before' it exexutes

Comment: That's the point of `command_not_found_handle`. Without it, nothing executes because there was no command found *to* execute. The function takes the invalid command line as input, and allows you to pick it apart, passing the arguments to another known command.

Comment: In fact, the function command_not_found_handle works in bash, but it seems that only command_not_found_handler works for zsh.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need is a [Bash alias](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html). An alias allows would allow you to define 'wonderful' as if it were a command. See the [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-bash-alias-examples/). For example, you can add:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
# -> Prevents accidentally clobbering files.
alias mkdir='mkdir -p'
```

to your ~/.bashrc file.

In your case you can alias "wonderful" to a script that handles the parameters or input, then invokes some other command.